# can get the value from map-get in SCSS

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

All right

Inside a component, I'm using the scss `map-get` method to get a specific value from a variable that I've defined in global scss file.

My class looks like this.

```
 .class{
  transition: background-color 500ms ease-out;
  background: var(--background-color);
  padding-top: map-get($site-section-padding,var(--padding-top));
  padding-bottom: map-get($site-section-padding, var(--padding-bottom));
}
```

And my variable

```
$site-section-padding: (
  'default': 0px,
  'XXS': 8px,
  'XS': 16px,
  'S': 24px,
  'M': 32px,
  'L': 40px,
  'XL': 56px,
  'XXL': 72px
);
```

Let's get a look into the paddings properties, the `map-get` get its value from the `var(--padding-#)` method, but i'm not getting anything. I think that `map-get` can not resolve the `var` method.

I do not have any issue to get the value from mapping when i directly use a string value, example `map-get($site-section-padding,'XS')`

So any ideas why it does not works and maybe some alternatives to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

### You cannot use CSS variables in Sass.

CSS variables get value at the runtime. Sass is a preprocessor. it can't read the value of a variable which will get value at runtime!

You can create your CSS var based on the SCSS variable:

```
$accent-color: #ff0000;
--accent-color: #{$accent-color};
```

Then in Sass function use `$accent-color` and in CSS Use `var(--accent-color)`.

### In your case

```
$padding-top: XS;
--padding-top: #{padding-top};
$padding-bottom: S;
--padding-bottom: #{padding-bottom};

.class{
  transition: background-color 500ms ease-out;
  background: var(--background-color);
  padding-top: map-get($site-section-padding,$padding-top);
  padding-bottom: map-get($site-section-padding, $padding-bottom);
}
```